# Remove part of URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a url like this `http://example.com/blog/photos/photos/gallery/image/1`.

And i need to remove the second photos folder. How do i remove the part using `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess`?

For your interest /blog is my document root.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions, Steve

**EDIT**

You should know that the URLs being generated by Wordpress 3.0 und NextgenGallery.

`http://example.com/blog` is my document root. That means i have installed  Wordpress into the folder `blog`.

The first slug after `blog` is the page i have my gallery associated with.

The second slug is the name of the album and could be renamed to everything you want. It is just a placeholder for my galleries. `gallery` is the name of the gallery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want to do a redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/photos/photos/(.*)$ /blog/photos/$1 [R]
```

Comment: +1. BTW since I'm learning mod_rewrite what's '[R]' why didn't you use '[301,L]' permanent redirect?

Comment: R just stands for redirect. Look at all the options here to figure out what is correct for your scenario: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: Taylor,

thank you for your fast response. But i really don't know if a simple redirect solves the problem. See my edit above please...

Any further suggestions?

Steve

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't solve the problem? Your edit doesn't really explain what you think the problem is that clearly.

Comment: Taylor, you're right. I can't explain why it did not work but now it works. I'm pretty sure something went wrong with my cms configuration. Now everything is fine :) Thank you very much.